# Stole the Temptress, How Can I Upgrade It?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I just stole the *Temptress*, looks like a cross between a Porsche and a Lamborghini I *think*. This is the car I would like to keep with as much damage resistance I can buy. I am trying to upgrade it. I have even purchased *Rim Jobs* the car garage found in most districts. But there are no options to upgrade my car. How can I upgrade my car?

I am currently on Angel's mission. Does that matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are quite a few cars that you will steal during a quest that can't be stored or upgraded.

Luckily, there are more Temptresses around - this is not a unique car for this mission.  You'll just have to get lucky and find one outside of a mission, or wait for the mission to end (or quit it...) and hope you get to keep it.

Once you find one, you should be able to take it to any garage (either at your crib or an owned/unowned Rim Jobs) to upgrade it or change its appearance.

The Saints Row Wikia has a [Temptress](http://saintsrow.wikia.com/wiki/Temptress) article, which lists common locations to find it, as well as a complete listing of the potential upgrades.

Comment: @desaivv, do note that I don't think this works for every vehicle - I think there are some where you'll get out of the car if you quit the mission, although I haven't tested this exhaustively.

Comment: @desaivv, I mean that there may be certain missions where you don't get to keep the car if you quit.  (I'm thinking of missions where they provide you with a car that is special, for instance)

Comment: @desaivv, that's [Natalie Lander](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1130176/).  Typically a new question is the best way, but for asking about voice actors and such, I'd probably suggest asking in chat.